# In Python, is it possible to access the class which contains a method, given only a method object?

Tags: python, decorator

I'm pretty new to Python, and haven't been able to find an answer to this question from searching online.

Here is an example decorator that does nothing (yet)

```
def my_decorator(text):
  def wrap(f):
    # grab magic f.parent_class_object.my_var and append text
    def wrap_f(*args, **kwargs):
      f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap_f
  return wrap
```

Here is an example class

```
class MyClass:
  my_var = []

  @my_decorator('sometext')
  def my_func()
    # do some super cool thing
```

In my decorator i'd like to access the class object for `MyClass` and add in 'sometext' to the `MyClass.my_var` list.  My goal is to populate my_var with decorated values at **module load** time, not function call time.

Is there a way i can navigate from `f` to `MyClass` in order to do this?  I know that *args[0] is the instance of MyClass, but that is only available when the function is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to read it from a function inside a class decorator, since the "methods" are still normal function while the class is being compiled. Also, the class name has not been defined while it is being compiled.

What you could do is supply the `my_var` list to the decorator.

```
class MyClass:
    my_var = []

    @my_decorator(my_var, 'sometext')
    def my_func()
        # do some super cool thing
```

`my_var` is still a normal variable by then.